# validation control not working

Tags: 2013, validation

I am using sharepoint validation control to validate only numbers but whatever i enter it says "please enter valid number". What is wrong with my validation expression?

```
<SharePoint:InputFormRegularExpressionValidator ID="NumberValidator"  runat="server" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"
                        ControlToValidate="txtMobile" BreakBefore="true" ErrorMessage="Please nter valid number"  ValidationExpression="^[0-9]$"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi actualy your validation express is correct same working for me but it was allowing spaces so i tried bellow mentioned validation express. try this and let me know whether it was helpfull or not.

```
\d+
```

If you want more details about the validation regular expression you can visit bellow mentioned link

[Regular expression for validation controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx)

Comment: its working with your answer. Not sure why not working with my validatoin expression

Comment: I am also not Sure why your exp is not working, if you feel answer was usefull mark it as answer and vote it, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your Regular Expression will only work for 1 digit. To accept 1 or more digits, change it to `^[0-9]+$`. To accept 0 or more digits, change it to `^[0-9]*$`